# unable to delete wamp folder even after uninstalling wamp server

Tags: mysql, wamp, directory

I can not delete my WAMP/bin/mysql folder in C drive, whenever I press delete a dialog box appears with: The action can not be completed because the file is open in another program.
close the file and try again.
NOTE: I have already uninstalled the wamp server.
Any help will be appreciable and respect for resolving this problem.  please help

Comment: Sorry to say that, but have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: try closing all folders or programs if any r open and try to delete it again

Comment: yes i tried but I un-installed it then checked the C drive and WAMP folder appears there. then I pressed delete but it says unable to delete

Comment: yes I closed every thing and ried again to delete but nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall wamp and if folder appears and unable to delete please follow these steps:

1. open task manger by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> and check for wamp server in applications. If not found then follow 2nd step
2. type `regedit` in cmd and open HKEY_CURRENT_USER open software option in it and find wamp by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. If wamp found press delete.
3. restart the system and open C drive and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> on wamp folder.

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall wamp. Then, go to Task Manager >> services .. then stop wamp related services. After that delete wamp folder.